# How to configure MFA for WireGuard VPN

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, wireguard, sysadmin

I have a WireGuard VPN on  linux to create a secure tunnel to my server and clients.

I want to add MFA functionality for user connections. I would like require entering a security code when connecting.

I am unable to configure MFA functionality. Ccan you help me? Give me some ideas, a hint on how to configure it please.

Comment: You're unable because WireGuard doesn't provide such feature. It provides a building brick over which you (or someone else) have to create your own solution (or buy one already created). Here are bones: https://lwn.net/Articles/910766/ , https://github.com/netbirdio/netbird?tab=readme-ov-file#secure-peer-to-peer-vpn-with-sso-and-mfa-in-minutes